# Calculating probability of success vs failure

Tags: probability, dice

Hoping I can get some help in understanding the raw math behind this.  I understand basic probabilities, but sometimes these things are either a bit more complicated than I can work out - or I tend to overthink it and miss the obvious  O.o

I'm playing a game, in which we roll a certain # of dice (all 6 sided - standard, fair dice).

In the simple case, if we roll a 1, that die is considered a failure.

So if we roll 1 die, the chances of getting 0 failures is:  5/6

If we roll 2 dice, chance of getting 0 failures is: (5/6)*(5/6) = 25/36

or if I have this right, in a general sense chances of no failures on n dice:

(5^n)/(6^n) or (5/6)^n

And hence getting any failures is:   1 - ( (5/6)^n )

I hope I have that correct so far ..

This much I understand .. however, where I get lost, is when there are different dice.

Let's say we have two types of dice: White and Red dice.

```
White dice, when rolled, fail on a roll of 1.
Red dice, when rolled, fail on a roll of 1 or 2.
```

So ... given that I'm rolling n White dice, and k Red dice ...

what's the odds of:

```
a) no failures on any dice
b) 1 failure only
c) 2 failures only
d) 3 or more failures.
```

Note: as I've perused some suggested threads as I post this .. i want to clarify - this question has no "order" - that is, I'm not asking for "2 failures in a row" ... but rather just "2 failures .. period".   so no order to the dice roll .. we just roll n dice all at once.

I saw this thread:
[Probability of an event happening more times than at least one other event](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562880/probability-of-an-event-happening-more-times-than-at-least-one-other-event)
It seemed .. "similar" .. but seems more complex than what i'm asking, I think?

I've tried setting up an xls to calc each set seperately, and "add them", however, I don't believe it's coming up with the proper answer.

Note: for those interested, my question stems from this game:   https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/256589/rallyman-gt
and as I learn games, I like to really understand and dig into the underlying math of things and would really like to understand how to (properly) calculate the odds of hitting 3+ failures (ie to better understand my risk vs reward in the game) Hoping this is fine, as the question is purely about the math - the game is simply for background/understanding the question.

Comment: What do you think are the odds of 0 failures when rolling one red die?

Comment: This is simply two [binomial distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) occurring alongside one another.  Letting $p_w$ be probability of failure for a white die, and $p_r$ for failure for a red die... $n$ white dice and $k$ red dice... you have zero failures is $(1-p_w)^n(1-p_r)^k$.  You have 1 failure is $np_w(1-p_w)^{n-1}(1-p_r)^k+kp_r(1-p_w)^n(1-p_r)^{k-1}$ and so on... having to break into cases based on how many of each type of die had a failure shown.

Comment: The probability of 3 or more failures is $1$ minus the probability of no failures, 1 failure, or 2 failures.

Comment: @DotCounter  obviously it should be (4/6)^k ... but my real question is the combining of it ... not the individual dice odds.  I tried to demonstrate I have that basic understanding already.

Comment: @JMoravitz  yes, fair .. but how to calculate those mid ones - is there an easy formula? or it a must be iterative process?

Comment: @Ditto So, what is your best guess as to the odds of 0 failures with 1 red and 1 white die?

Comment: We're getting into a lot of named variables... I'll talk about one for now.  If we have $n$ white dice, probability of failure is $p$... the probability to get exactly $a$ failures will be $\binom{n}{a}p^a(1-p)^{n-a}$.  That is the binomial distribution.  Now... to get a combined total of $a$ failures... you will need to get some amount of them as white failures and another amount as red failures.  You can find the probability of a specific number of white and a specific number of red by multiplying together... By adding all of the possible cases together you get the final combined total.

Comment: @DotCounter  that's what I'm asking ... what I have in my excel isn't doing it properly .. so I'm obviously losing it around this point .. ;)     in meantime .., I'm trying to parse JMoravitz comment .. it's making some sense .. and just trying to build on it.

Comment: To get 7 total failures... you look at 0 white failures and 7 red failures, 1 white failure and 6 red failures, etc...  The probability for 3 white failures and 4 red failures for instance being $\binom{n}{3}p_w^3(1-p_w)^{n-3}\binom{k}{4}p_r^4(1-p_r)^{k-4}$ using the variable names I used before... $n$ white dice, $k$ red dice, $p_w$ probability of failure for each white die, $p_r$ probability of failure for each red die

Comment: @Ditti You understand that adding a more white dice takes you from (5/6) to (5/6)(5/6) odds to (5/6)^k, and that adding more red dice take you from (4/6) to (4/6)(4/6) to (4/6)^k... but what stops you from adding red dice to white dice using a similar thought process?

Comment: @JMoravitz  ok yeah .. this is where I got hung up .. I got the binomial distrbution formala at one point .. I recognize it - its what I have in my xls ...  you then state " .. get some amount of them as white failures and another amount of red failures" ... this is where I got lost ...

Comment: To get 7 total failures... you must have gotten 0 white and 7 red failures, or 1 white and 6 red failures, or yada yada.  The probability of 7 total failures then is the probability of getting exactly 0 white and 7 red, plus the probability of getting 1 white and 6 red, plus the probability of getting 2 white and 5 red, etc...

Comment: Could we write this a different way?  Sure... but it won't help.  You could say the probability of $m$ total failures will be the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $(p_wx+(1-pw))^n(p_rx+(1-p_r))^k$, which you can see by expanding each by binomial theorem, and then multiplying each sum together... the expression expanded as $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{n+k}\sum\limits_{i=0}^m\binom{n}{i}\binom{k}{m-i}p_w^ip_r^{m-i}(1-p_w)^{n-i}(1-p_r)^{k-m+i}x^m$.  Again, I do not think it is useful to think of it this way, and far prefer thinking of it using binomial distributions as building blocks and logic.

Comment: @JMoravitz  yep .. and you lost me!!  LOL   yeah, I think that formula/ explanation you have up a prior to my previous post explains it best .. I'm still parsing it .. but I think I understand it ... thank you!  this helps a lot!  The combination of the (x choose y) * (some exponential term) for the probabilty I've always found a bit tricky to get to sometimes.  I can read it . I can understand it once I see it ... but I can't get there on my own :P   Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JMoravitz has noted in the comments, what we have here is effectively two independent binomial distributions. In general, when you have multiple independent events, and want to know the probability of the outcome of both, we simply take the product of those probabilities. I'll show both these distributions separately, then show what they look like once we've multiplied them together.

Let's define the number of white dice as $w$ and the number of red dice as $r$. We'll define the number of white failures as $j$ and the number of red failures as $k$. We can calculate the probability of an arbitrary number of white dice failures as:

$$P(W=j)=\binom{w}{j}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{w-j}$$

Note that $\binom{w}{j}$ is the binomial coefficient, which is calculated as $\binom{w}{j}=\frac{w!}{j!(w-j)!}$. The probability of an arbitrary number of red dice failures is calculated as:

$$P(R=k)=\binom{r}{k}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^k\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{r-k}$$

Exactly the same equation, just with red's variables. So, the probability of $j$ white failures *and* $k$ red failures is just a matter of multiplying these two together:

$$P(R=k \cap W=j)=\binom{w}{j}\binom{r}{k}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{w-j}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^k\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{r-k}$$

Of course, the question you have is slightly different than this - we want to know the *total* failures, not an arbitrary combination. Let's define the total number of failures rolled as $f$. There's more than one combination of $j$ and $k$ that will get us any given total, so we'll need to do this calculation for each possibility, then sum all the probabilities together. In this case that's pretty straightforward - $j$ and $k$ both count for the same number of failures, so we can just set $k=f-j$, and use $j$ as our iterator (we could also do the opposite, and set $j=f-k$ and use $k$ as the iterator, it honestly doesn't matter here). We'll have run through all the possibilities of interest when $j$ has been either every value up to $f$, every value up to $r$, or every value up to $w$, so we'll set the end value of our iterator to be the lowest of those three. That looks like:

$$P(F=f)=\sum_{j=0}^{\min(w,r,f)}\binom{w}{j}\binom{r}{f-j}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{w-j}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{f-j}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{r-(f-j)}$$

Let's test it out! Let's look at the possibility of 2 failures with 5 white dice and 3 red dice. So, that's $f=2$, $w=5$ & $r=3$. Let's plug in those numbers and see what we get:

$$\begin{align*}
P(F=2)=&\sum_{j=0}^{\min(5,3,2)}\binom{5}{j}\binom{3}{2-j}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{5-j}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{2-j}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{3-(2-j)}\\
=&\sum_{j=0}^{2}\binom{5}{j}\binom{3}{2-j}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^j\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{5-j}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{2-j}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{1+j}\\
=&\binom{5}{0}\binom{3}{2}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^0\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{5}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{2}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{1}+\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^1\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{4}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{1}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{2}\\
&+\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{0}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right )^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right )^{3}\left(\frac{2}{6}\right )^{0}\left(\frac{4}{6}\right )^{3}\\
=&1\cdot 3 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{3125}{7776}\cdot\frac{4}{36}\cdot \frac{4}{6}+5\cdot 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{625}{1296}\cdot\frac{2}{6}\cdot\frac{16}{36}+10 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{36}\cdot\frac{125}{216}\cdot 1 \cdot \frac{64}{216}\\
=& \frac{3125}{34992}+\frac{6250}{34992}+\frac{625}{13122}=\frac{33125}{104976}\approx 0.3155483\\
\end{align*}$$

So, if you have 5 white dice and 3 red dice, you have around a 31% chance of 2 failures. This basic calculation will work for any single value of $f$, and if you're looking for a range, you'll need to repeat this calculation for every value of $f$ you're interested in, then add the whole thing together (so, for 3+ failures, you'll need to calculate $f=3$, $f=4$,$f=5$, etc. As a quick tip though, if you've included a larger range of failure values than you are excluding, you can save yourself some work by calculating the probabilities of items you are *excluding* instead, then subtracting those values from 1. In general, you should never have to calculate more than half the total possible range with this trick, although admittedly if it's a large number of dice, that can still be a lot of equation to calculate.

Comment: Thanks for that write up .. this will take me some time to work through .. but I have a question on that first formula ... as I understood in a simple fashion, to calculate rolling n white dice (ie 1 in 6 to fail) , with no failures rolled on any, should be (5/6)^n ?  But your formula shows the (5/6)^(w-j) ... where w-j  would be "n-n" (ie all successes) .., or (5/6)^0 ??   I'm I reading that right? or did you flip those two ie the (1/6)^j  *  (5/6)^(w-j)   ==>   (1/6)^(w-j)  *  (5/6)^j     ??    white dice "fail" 1 in 6 .. so success in 5 in 6 ?

Comment: actually I see what's wrong .. formula you have is right .. the paragraph prior to the first formula is wrong .. you refer to  "We'll define the number of white successes as j
 and the number of red successes as k"   but that should read "We'll define the number of white failures as j and the number of red failures as k"  ... As later you actually refer to j and k as the # of failures ?  Am I understanding that right?

Comment: If $f=0$, then obviously we only have one iteration of our sum (because 0 will always be the minimum number), where $j=0$, $w-j=w$, $f-j=0$ and $r-(f-j)=r$, $\binom{w}{j}=\binom{w}{0}=1$, and \binom{r}{f-j}=\binom{r}{0}=1. Since $x^0=1$ for all $x$ in this equation, it all reduces down to $P(F=0)=(\frac{5}{6})^w(\frac{4}{6})^r$. So, if we have $n$ white dice and 0 red dice then yes, you're looking at $(\frac{5}{6})^n$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that's a mistake, I'll fix that. I mean, what a "success" and "failure" are here is pretty arbitrary! Usually this is done in reverse, with "successes" being $j$/$k$, and failures being $w-j$/$r-k$, but considering the way you wrote it, I tried to make some changes to the explanation to make it a bit simpler, clearly I still had successes on the brain!

Comment: yep, trying to wrap my brain around, I tend to read things very carefully .. and something didn't look right .. ;)  I'm glad it was just the definition ... rest of your formulas make perfect sense now .. and I was *VERY* close to that with the xls prior to posting, but for some reason, there were some side cases that weren't coming up right proving I didn't have everything correct .. and I couldn't put a finger on it ... JMoravitz and you helped out perfectly ... I was able to iron out my xls , and I believe I can see where I made my mistake.   Thank you all for the explanations .. :)

Comment: and yes, I am just calculating the 0, 1 and 2 cases .. and for 3+ doing 1-(sum of 0,1,2) ;)   I had that previously and knew to do that ... I think my somehow my 2 case was mucked up .. oh well.

Comment: Let me guess - it was the $\min(w,r,f)$ part of the sum loop? That's not part of the binomial definition - that's something I've learned from experience: anything you're subtracting your iterator from needs to be part of the conditions to end the sum, especially if they're left as variables! In a lot of cases it won't cause problems, but when it *does* cause problems...

Comment: Davis-Thalbroune honestly not sure ... I didn't go over my old code too closely and can't remember .. but yeah, most likely it was something along the combining of it .. that's why I figured to come here for a hand ... ;)   Appreciate the point in the right direction. thanks again.